# What is the spin-orbit force?

Tags: nuclear-physics, atomic-physics, quantum-spin

I am trying to brush up on my physics knowledge, and I have run across a term used to justify some results in a few texts that I don't recognize, the spin-orbit force $\vec s \cdot \vec l$. Quickly googling around has not yielded much, if any information, and it's just brushed over as being trivial in texts (as are most concepts, I'm finding). Would anyone be able to explain this concept to me, either conceptually or mathematically? My apologies if I'm just missing a core concept I should know inherently, my education is not in physics.

Comment: It’s basically magnetic. What part of [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin–orbit_interaction)’s explanation do you need help understanding?

Comment: Primarily that spin-orbit interaction is the same as spin-orbit force! My apologies, I appear to have fallen victim to inconsistent terminology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magnetic fields repel or attract each other.

An electric charge performing a rotation (angular momentum $\mathbf{L}$) generates a magnetic field $\mathbf{B}_1 \propto \mathbf{L}$.

An electron has an intrinsic magnetic field (as if it had a bar magnetc inside) due to its *spin* $\mathbf{S}$, $\mathbf{B}_2\propto \mathbf{S}$.

These two magnetic fields have an interaction that goes as $\mathbf{B}_1 \cdot \mathbf{B}_2$, and hence $\mathbf{L} \cdot \mathbf{S}$.